# for loop in php iteration

Tags: php, sql, arrays

```
$j=0;
for ($i=0; $i<31 ; $i++) {
    $t_bills = 0;
    # code...
    if($i<9){
        $j='0'.($i+1);
    }else{
        $j=($i+1);
    }
    $finaldate= $current_year.'-'.$current_month.'-'.$j;
    echo "............";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "finsal date is";
    echo("<br>");
    echo $finaldate;
    echo "</br>";
    //print_r($row);
    $tt_bills=0;
    //echo mysqli_num_rows($run);
    $strQuery ="SELECT bills,r_date FROM  daily_machine_record where (`r_date` = '$finaldate' )";
    $run= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$strQuery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
    {
        if($finaldate==$row['r_date']){
            for ($x=0; $x <mysqli_num_rows($run) ;$x++ ) {

                echo "............";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $finaldate;
                echo "<br>";
                echo "bill is";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['bills'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo "............";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $tt_bills +=  $row['bills'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo "............";
                echo("<br>");
    //var_dump($tt_bill);
            }
        }
        else{

            echo $tt_bills =$tt_bills+ 0;
        }
    }
```

i want to get the value of bills at each date of current month which is stored in my database. im having a problem .i.e when the loop executes it generates the bills amount but where the date is same it returns the value incrementing it 2 times like if the value is 100 on 2017:11:06 and on same date i have another value 100 the total amount of bills which i get will be 400 instead of 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your else condition. Re-assign only `0` to variable

```
else{

 echo $tt_bills =  0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Also remove un-necessary `for loop` other wise your result will be repeated

Comment: it is returing same output. like if i have 3 records on same date it returns the the amount of 9 records like if 10 ,10 ,10 should be 30 it returns 90 instead

Comment: You have multiple loop. Remove `for ($x=0; $x <mysqli_num_rows($run) ;$x++ ) {` as `while ` is doing job what you want

Comment: life saver . yes it was indeed the issue.